# Authentication with a Java Restful Service

Tags: java, rest, jersey, java-ee-6, basic-authentication

I am trying to get a Java EE jersey restful service with basic authentication working on Glassfish v3.

Currently, the service asks for the user to be authenticated and if the correct credentials are provided, allows any user within the realm (with any role) access to the service. It should only be allowing the admin role access.

Additionally, if I try to restrict using the @RolesAllowed annotation this also is ignored.

The rest code:

```
@Path("/file")
public class FileResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getJson() {
        String result = "{\"data\":\"test\"}";
        return Response.ok(result, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    public Response getOther() {
        String result = "{\"employee\":[{\"email\":\"jdoe@example.com\",\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\"},{\"email\":\"mmajor@example.com\",\"firstName\":\"Mary\",\"lastName\":\"Major\"}]}";
        return Response.ok(result, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

The web.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>org.examples.secure</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>DBRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>users</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <!-- <user-data-constraint>
            <description>SSL</description>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint> -->
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

</web-app>
```

The sun-web.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Servlet 2.5//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_5-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/org.examples.secure</context-root>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</sun-web-app>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 1. The roles defined in the web.xml don't have any effect (as long as the user is in the realm defined that can access the service - I am currently trying to restrict it to the admin role). 2. The same applies to the @RolesAllowed annotation

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory.html) to your web application (see the linked javadoc on how) for the @RolesAllowed annotations to work.